# Wait for a server message in background in React Native

Tags: react-native

I'm developing a Messenger/Call app in React Native. Users can call each other. When all users are online there is no problem but when users go offline (close their app) they won't recognize calls. I need to run a service which listens to a specific types of message pushed by server.
I want to publish call signals by google GSM. (I can't use Firebase for some reasons)

Is there any library which I can use it or I have to define my own native module and Link it to React Native?

Comment: You can use `Headless JS` that is a way to run tasks in JavaScript while your app is in the background. (https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/headless-js-android)